# Instagram upload picture problem

Tags: iphone, instagram

While uploading pictures to Instagram I am getting the following error:

> Could not open photo. Please try again in a moment

The phone storage seems to be low, deleting pictures and restarting the have not been helpful.

Comment: Have you *optimised storage*? Is the photo available offline?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii yes, under iCloud "optimize iphone storage" was enabled. Turning it off and making sure that the pictures' originals are available resolved the issue. Please convert your comment to an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under iCloud Preferences, *optimize iphone storage* should be disabled. Turning it off and making sure that the pictures' originals are available(by opening & then trying to edit it) should resolve the issue.